# route is not loading component inside nested route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm loading my `adminDashboard` component in `app.js` with `Route`. now in `adminDashboard` based on URL, I want to render some component. but, it's not loading any component. also, there is no activity on the network tab in chrome console.

if I render them without Route, they are rendering properly.

app.js

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    let { error, success } = this.props;
    const Admin = Authorization(['admin'])
    return (
      <div className='app'>
        <AdminNavbar logout={this.props.logout}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/admin/signin' render={(props) => {
              return <AuthForm />
            }}
          />
          <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin(AdminDashboard)} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MyComponent component

```
const MyDashboard = (props)=> ` this is dashboard`
```

Admindashboard

```
class AdminDashboard extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-md-2'>
                        <NavBar  />
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-md-10'>
                        < Commisions /> //working properly if i load it without route
                        <Switch>

                            <Route exact path='/admin/dashboard' component={MyDashboard} /> // not work
                            //some other route
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the `products` and `commision` that are not working for you? Are `/admin/faqs` and `/admin/check` working fine?

Comment: none of them is working. i remove `/admin` from `/products` route to see if it's working

Comment: `/products` and `/commision` would not work because they don't have the `/admin` prefix, the last two should work. Can you create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: it's working now. i have to  remove `exact` from `admin` route in `app.js`, otherwise there are no component for `admin/route` to render.